# How Long Does it Take for Pending Robux to Go Into Your Account?

Tags: roblox

I got some robux from the donation game Starving Artists. In my transactions, it says that I have "Pending Robux". How long is it until the actual robux goes into my account?

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. But I'm curious - is this "pending" status still a thing? Or at the minimum, is it something much shorter now (like 10 minutes or less?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time this was posted, there was a delay in Robux, with a 30 day resolution time according to a [Roblox employee](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/group-payouts-are-missing-30-of-in-experience-avatarugc-commissions/2722905/2):

> there is a delay in the release of Robux. The team has resolved this issue and all previous sales will be released in 30 days.